# Wordpress html element 100% width on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, width

I'm trying to make my wordpress site always display with 100% width. My wordpress-css has no mobile specific css. When I visit the site on mobile, the site is not longer 100% width, despite the css saying that it should be. I'm currently testing stuff in the css and therefore not linking the site.

**EDIT: I now tried removing all width-specifications in the entire css, the word "width" is not present anywhere in the css. The html still locks to exactly 320 pixels, same as the width specified by the iPhone4. This could be an issue with wordpress and not the css file.**

[image: Width is not 100%]
[image: Min-width given as 100% in css]

The really weird thing is that if I scale up the window, and then scale it back down, it looks like it should look:

[image: Scaling up, now it's 100% width]
[image: If I scale it back down now, it's still 100%]

This is the css:

```
body, html {
    font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333; 
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I have the viewport-thing at the top of my html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

However I have not been able to add the "initial-scale=1" into the wordpress html. From what I read I doubt that this is the problem though.

Any suggestions what could be wrong? As a sidenote: It does fail to display 100% width on an actual mobile device as well, it's not just the chrome device simulator failing.

A hint could be that it seems that even wordpress itself misjudges the width of the screen, as can be seen by the wordpress header not filling up 100%

Comment: you should either reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so, or provide a link to a site which reproduces the issue..

Comment: Good idea! I edited in the link.

Comment: try max-width: 100% and overflow: hidden on your body element to see if its child content expanding the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By request of rsn, I will sum up our discussion as an answer. Creds to rsn and everyone else for finding the issue!

In this case, the width itself is set properly. The problem is that things move outside the 100% width and the site tries to scale everything down to fit the stuff moving outside of 100% width. This caused everything else to scale down, including the font size of the text which I thought was an entirely different problem. So, after specifying:

```
.img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The site worked fine. Except for one last detail, I also has a really long link that, despite having word-wrap: break-word, ended up being wider than the width. To solve this I added:

```
.long-link {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

And now nothing moves outside the 100% width, and everything works as it should.